# AngularJS Filter, set class of of label and input field with validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, filter, input-field

I have an Angular app with a list of F1 drivers. I want to put a filter on the table, so I can get drivers by their first or by their last name.
To make this I use following design:
[image: text input validation]

Normally the label and the line of the input are black. I want to check if the input value only is a String value (a-zA-Z). I use following code in my partial view:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError">input must be [a-zA-Z]</label>
    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
        <input ng-model="nameFilter" type="text" name="nameFilter" class="form-control empty" placeholder="Search Driver name...">
        <span class="material-input"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This input value is bound with following filter (declared in my controller.js)

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (driver) {
    var re = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
        if(! (/[^a-zA-Z]+/).test($scope.nameFilter)){
            $scope.nameFilter.class ='control-label';
        }
    return !$scope.nameFilter || re.test(driver.Driver.givenName) || re.test(driver.Driver.familyName);
};
```

But this doesn't work..  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**

Your Regular expression is wrong, check out its validity [here](https://regex101.com/)

change it from

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/
```

to

```
/^[A-Za-z]+$/
```

Comment: How do I make the label red?

Comment: give the label a class or an id and then set its colour using css